# Connection for a user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have for my table 'Student' 5 fields `id, name, firstname, email, phone`.

My question: I would like the user to connect by putting his name what should I change?

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {   
        $user = $request->user();
        $students= Student::query()
        ->when($user->hasRole('admin') !== true, function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('email', $user->email);
        })
        ->when($request->has('search'), function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search').'%');
        })
        ->paginate(5);



    return view('admin.students.index', compact('students'))
        ->with('display_search', $user->hasRole('admin'));
    }
```

Here:

```
$query->where('email', $user->email);
```

I have to put this?

```
  $query->where('name', $user->name);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean `connect`? do you want to change the login credentials from `email and password` to `name and password` for users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the authentication credential from `email` to another column in the user's table, override the username function in the `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`

```php
/**
 * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function username()
{
    return 'name';
}
```